# JavaScript Syntax: actual = node.nodeType === 1 && node.getAttribute(att)

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in JavaScript. I'm reading the book JavaScript: The Good Parts. On page 35, it has the code:

```
    ...
    walk_the_DOM(document.body, function (node) {
        var actual = node.nodeType === 1 && node.getAttribute(att);
        if (typeof actual === 'string' && (actual === value || typeof value !== 'string')) {
            results.push(node);
        }
});
```

I'm confuse about the value of the variable actual. Why is it a string type? Is it should be boolean type?

Comment: The `&&` and `||` operators are a little "weird" in JavaScript.  They don't return boolean values.  Instead they return either the 1st or the 2nd argument.

Comment: `actual` can be the boolean false if `node.nodeType !== 1`

Comment: I found the answer on page 16. I missed that sentence before.

The && operator produces the value of its first operand if the first
 operand is falsy. Otherwise, it produces the value of the second  operand.